# Room with Kotlin-coroutines observe db changes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

So, I recently started experimentation with coroutines, I switched from Rxjava2 to coroutines, I haven't got a grasp of it yet but still, I ran into a condition where I needed to observe my database change and update the UI corresponding to that.

RxJava used to provide me with Flowables, Completeable etc.  using that I would be able to observe changes in Db.

```
    abstract fun insert(data: SomeData): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
    abstract fun getData(): Flowable<List<SomeData>>
```

So here now I used to subscribe to getData and always used to observe changes

Now Enter coroutines, I am using a suspended function with a deferred result to return my responses

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(data: SomeData): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
    abstract fun getData(): List<SomeData>
```

```
suspend fun getAllSomeData():Deferred<List<SomeData>>{
        return GlobalScope.async (context= coroutineContext){
            database.myDao().getData()
        }
    }
```

Now I have no way to listen for updates, **Channels** in coroutines might be the right answer? but I am not sure how to use it with Room.

Comment: Simply use `LiveData`. It will meet all your requirement and is a part of new Android JetPack library.

Comment: " listen for updates"  why not make use of `Observable` ?

Comment: The thing is i know that it can be done with livedata and rxjava.But i specifically wanted to use coroutines with it.

Comment: yes, you can use channels - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54534038/7212836

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use **Room 2.2.0 Flows** and **kotlin coroutines**.  It's contentious but I dislike **LiveData** as it gives you results on the UI thread.  If you have to do any data parsing you'll have to push everything back to another IO thread.  It's also cleaner than using **channels** directly as you have to do extra **openSubscription().consumeEach { .. }** calls every time you want to listen to events.

Flow approach Requires the following versions:

// this version uses coroutines and flows in their non-experimental version

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2
androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0
androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {
     @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
     fun getData(): Flow<List<SomeData>>
}
```

class to do observation:

```
launch {
   dao.getData().collect { data ->
    //handle data here
   }
}
```

if your calling class is not itself a **CoroutineScope** you'd have to call launch with the context of something that is.  That can be **GlobalScope** or some other class you create.  Here I'm using lifecycleScope assuming we're in an Activity class.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
   dao.getData().collect { data ->
    //handle data here
   }
}
```

the **collect** lambda will receive every udpate to the table much like an Rx **onNext** call.

Comment: What's the difference between Flow and LiveData?

Comment: flows bind to a coroutine scope while LiveData requires you specify a lifecycle and generate observables.  That's one of the reason I prefer the coroutine approach.  namely, it doesn't require so much crufty setup.  In the end they have the same result of posting data back to the View.   NOTE:  there are supposedly new lifecycle extension methods to help binding flows to android architecture lifecycles.  I have not tried these yet.

Comment: But flows cannot be used with databinding, am i right? So at the moment it's better to use Livedata?
I don't know which way to go... there are livedata, observables, flow. At last i decided to use livedata because that are used often by google in examples.

Comment: I don't know enough about databinding specifically to answer that.  I was speaking mainly to Room and MVP patterns.   I would leave LiveData for sending data to the UI if that's your architecture.  LiveData inside database calls or network events is still a bad idea based on the threading restrictions I mentioned.

Comment: Using GlobalScope launch is not recommended because it creates global coroutines and these coroutines are not children of some specific scope.

Comment: haven't been following this thread.  These days a more appropriate scope would be either the viewModel coroutine scope or Activity lifecyclescope you get from AndroidX.

Answer (score 9):

Currently, there are two different ways of doing that. The first is to use a liveData builder function. To make this work, you need to update lifecycle to `androidx.lifecycle:*:2.2.0-alpha01` or any newer version. The LiveData builder function will be used to call getData() asynchronously, and then use emit() to emit the result. Using this method, you will modify your Room getData() function to a suspend function and make the return type wrapped as a LiveData, replacing the Flowable used before.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
abstract suspend fun getData(): LiveData<List<SomeData>>
```

In your viewmodel you create a liveData which references your Room database

```
val someData: LiveData<SomeData> = liveData {
    val data = database.myDao().getData() 
    emit(data)
}
```

The second approach is to get data from our DB as Flow. To use this, you need to update Room to `androidx.room:room-*:2.2.0-alpha02` (currently the latest) or a  newer version. This update enables @Query DAO methods to be of return type Flow The returned Flow will re-emit a new set of values if the observing tables in the query are invalidated. Declaring a DAO function with a Channel return type is an error

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
abstract fun getData(): Flow<List<SomeData>?>
```

The return type is a flow of a nullable list. The list is nullable because Room will return null when the query has no data fetched.

To fetch data from the flow we will use the terminal operator `collect{ }` in our Presenter/ViewModel. It is preferable to do this in the ViewModel since it comes with a ViewModelScope. The solution given below assumes we are doing this in a ViewModel where we have a provided viewModelScope.

```
    fun loadData(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            database.myDao()
               .getData()
               .distinctUntilChanged().
               .collect{
                        it?.let{ /** Update your obsevable data here **/
               }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-reactive', version: '1.1.1'
}
```

**Room Dao**

```
@Dao
interface HistoryDao : BaseDao<HistoryEntity> {

    @Query("select * from History order by time desc")
    fun observe(): Flowable<List<HistoryEntity>>

    ...
}
```

**Interactor (*browserHistoryInteractor* below)** (layer between dao and Fragment/Presenter)

```
// To get channel of List<HistoryEntity>:
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.openSubscription

fun observe() = historyDao.observe().openSubscription() // convert list to Coroutines channel
```

**Presenter/Fragment/Activity** (end point (in my case it is lifecycle-aware presenter))

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

private val compositeJob = Job() // somewhat equivalent "compositeDisposable" in rx

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    launch(compositeJob) { // start coroutine
        val channel = browserHistoryInteractor.observe() 
        for (items in channel) {  // waits for next list of items (suspended)
            showInView { view?.setItems(items) }
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    compositeJob.cancel() // as in rx you need to cancel all jobs
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh2Vqt4DpHU&list=PLdb5m83JnoaBqMWF-qqhZY_01SNEhG5Qs&index=5 at 29:25