# execute room db queries async using coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, coroutine

what is the problem with the codes
db queries freeze ui.
every thing works , but freezing ui when running db query
what is the point that i dont know .
all queries make ui freeze,
when executing Delete query , recycleview animation freezing ,but after commenting the line that execute query , recycleview work smoothly

> hilt Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

@Provides
fun provideCardDao(passwordDatabase: PasswordDatabase): CardDao {
    return passwordDatabase.cardDao()
}

@Singleton 
@Provides
fun providesCoroutineScope(): CoroutineScope {
  
    return CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providePasswordDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext appContext: Context,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
): PasswordDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        appContext,
        PasswordDatabase::class.java,
        "mydb.db"
    )
        .addMigrations()
        .addCallback(MYDatabaseCallback(coroutineScope))
        .setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
}
}
```

> card Dao

```
@Dao
interface CardDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertCardDetails(cardDetails : BanksCardModel)


@Query("DELETE FROM CardDetailsTable WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun deleteCardDetails(id : Int)

@Query("SELECT * FROM CardDetailsTable WHERE id = :id")
 fun getOneCardDetails(id : Int):LiveData<BanksCardModel>

@Query("SELECT * FROM CardDetailsTable")
fun getAllCardDetails() : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM CardDetailsTable WHERE username LIKE '%' || :str || '%' OR bank_name LIKE '%' || :str || '%' "
)
 fun queryOnCards(str:String): LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>
}
```

> password db

```
@Database(entities = [ BanksCardModel::class],version = 15,exportSchema = false)
abstract class PasswordDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun cardDao() : CardDao
}
```

> repository

```
@Singleton
class Repository @Inject constructor(private val cardDao: CardDao) {

suspend fun insertCardDetails(cardDetailsItem: BanksCardModel){
    cardDao.insertCardDetails(cardDetailsItem)
}
suspend fun deleteCardDetails(id : Int){
    cardDao.deleteCardDetails(id)
}
 fun getOneCardDetails(id : Int):LiveData<BanksCardModel>{
    return cardDao.getOneCardDetails(id)
}
fun getAllCardDetails() : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>{
    return cardDao.getAllCardDetails()
}
 fun queryOnCards(str : String) : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>{
    return cardDao.queryOnCards(str)
}
}
```

> viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {

private var cardDetailsList : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>


init {
    cardDetailsList = repository.getAllCardDetails() 
}


fun insertCardDetails(cardDetailsItem: BanksCardModel)= viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insertCardDetails(cardDetailsItem)
}
 fun deleteCardDetails(id : Int)= viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.deleteCardDetails(id)
}
fun getOneCardDetails(id : Int):LiveData<BanksCardModel>{
   return repository.getOneCardDetails(id)
}
fun getAllCardDetails() : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>{
    return cardDetailsList
}

  fun queryOnCards(str:String) : LiveData<List<BanksCardModel>>{
         return repository.queryOnCards(str)
}

}
```

////edited

> query in searchview

```
       override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                    viewModel.queryOnCards(newText?:"").collect{
                        val searchedList = it.toMutableList()
                        showingEmptyListAnnounce(searchedList)
                        adapter.updateList(searchedList)
                    }
            }

            return true
        }
```

> the update list function in onQueryTextChange -- its using DiffUtils

```
       fun updateList( updatedList : MutableList<BanksCardModel>){

           val callback = CustomCallback(mList, updatedList)
           val result  = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback)
           mList.clear()
           mList.addAll(updatedList)
         result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
 }
```

[video of screen](https://www.veed.io/view/e020f206-c96b-4301-8bf9-1520f2deac23?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LiveData` is [outdated](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-livedata-to-kotlins-flow-379292f419fb). Please consider to use Kotlin `Flow`.

Here is your use case:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
   dao.getData().collect { data ->
    //handle data here
   }
}
@Dao
interface MyDao {
     @Query("SELECT * FROM somedata_table")
     fun getData(): Flow<List<SomeData>>
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454829/room-with-kotlin-coroutines-observe-db-changes)

There is a good [Google codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow#9) to practice Kotlin `coroutine` and `Room` queries

Also please consider to use `StrictMode` - it will show you this and similar issues in future.

Comment: wow thank you very much for fast responding, i am going to try it and then tell you my result

Comment: You are welcome. Consider to accept it as an answer if your origin question has been solved by it.

Comment: recycleview has lag , when i typing in search view , its typed with a delay ; i edit the question and add the code inside onQueryTextChange ; can you take a look at it?

Comment: Excuse me, I can not invest more time at this issue right now, but you could reference my app where I did similar use case. Here is the code: https://github.com/Gelassen/government-rus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/home/government/screens/laws/filter/LawsFilteredFragment.kt#L96 and https://github.com/Gelassen/government-rus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/home/government/screens/laws/BillsViewModel.kt#L50

Comment: you help alot thank you

Comment: the problem was in updating list , the way i used DiffUtils works but very slow , after seeing your code I realized that there is another way to implement DiffUtils . now it works as i expected